# strange opencl vector add behavior with nvidia (visual studio 2010)

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I had encountered this strange behavior when trying to compile an opencl vector addition kernel using nvidia (under visual studio 2010). I get the following outputs:

```
C[0]=1=0+1
C[1]=1.#INF=1+2
C[2]=-5.87747e-039=2+3
C[3]=-1.76324e-038=3+4
C[4]=-2.93874e-038=4+5
C[5]=-4.11423e-038=5+6
C[6]=-5.87747e-038=6+7
C[7]=-8.22846e-038=7+8
C[8]=-1.05794e-037=8+9
C[9]=-1.29304e-037=9+10
```

If i replace the operation in kernal

```
  C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
```

by assigning C with either A or B, without arithmetic operation, such as below:

```
  C[i] = A[i];
```

The output returned will be correct. I guess this means it read & write buffer correctly.

Also, it returned weird values when i replace the operation by assigning C with constant value, such as:

```
  C[i] = 999;
```

Here is my host program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#include <CL/cl.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    try {
std::cout<<"C"<<"\n";

std::ifstream ifs("vector_add.cl");
std::string kernelSource( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),
                       (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );

        cl_uint N = 10;
        std::vector<cl::Platform> platform1;
        cl::Platform::get(&platform1);
        std::vector<cl::Device> device1;
        //platform1.front().getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &device1);
        platform1.front().getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &device1);
        cl::Context context1 = cl::Context(device1);
        cl::Program::Sources src_code1;
        src_code1.push_back(std::make_pair(kernelSource.c_str(),kernelSource.size()));
        cl::Program program1 = cl::Program(context1, src_code1);
        program1.build(device1);
        cl::Kernel kernel1(program1, "vector_add");
        // Create a command queue and use the first device
        cl::Device& device1_addr = device1.front();
        cl::CommandQueue queue1(context1, device1_addr);

        float A[10], B[10], C[10];
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            A[i]=float(i);
            B[i]=1.0+i;
        }
        cl::Buffer A_buff(context1,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,sizeof(cl_float)*N);
        cl::Buffer B_buff(context1,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,sizeof(cl_float)*N);
        cl::Buffer C_buff(context1,CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,sizeof(cl_float)*N);
        queue1.enqueueWriteBuffer(A_buff, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_float)*N, A);
        queue1.enqueueWriteBuffer(B_buff, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_float)*N, B);
        kernel1.setArg(0,A_buff);
        kernel1.setArg(1,B_buff);
        kernel1.setArg(2,C_buff);

        queue1.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel1, 0, cl::NDRange(10), cl::NDRange(1));
        queue1.enqueueReadBuffer(C_buff, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_float)*N, C);
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            std::cout<<"C["<<i<<"]="<<C[i]<<"="<<A[i]<<"+"<<B[i]<<"\n";
        }
    } catch(cl::Error& err) {
        std::cerr << "OpenCL error: " << err.what() << "(" << err.err() <<
            ")" << std::endl;

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

while here is my kernel:

```
__kernel void vector_add(__global const int *A, __global const int *B, __global int *C) {

        // Get the index of the current element to be processed
        int i = get_global_id(0);



    // Do the operation
     C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
     //C[i] = B[i];
     //C[i] = 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel uses "__global const int *" for all its parameters, this should be "__global const float *" as your host code uses float.